# Diferencia de ?attr: con ?android:attr/ en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Cual es la diferencia de especificar valores en los atributos usando `?attr:` o bien usar `?android:attr/`

Por ejemplo para aplicar el color del texto como si fuese un control desactivado (gris suave)

Directamente:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />
```

usando ?android:attr/:

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondaryNoDisable" />
```

Valores extraidos de [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/9066cfe9886ac131c34d59ed0e2d287b0e3c0087/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)

Comment: Hola Webserveis, escribí mi respuesta en base a tu titulo pero con el ejemplo que pones creo que tu respondes a la pregunta, la diferencia es obtener directamente la propiedad desde el SDK con @android: o en base a tu definición dentro de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia es de donde obtienes los valores, en este caso los atributos, en el caso de usar:

```
?android:attr
```

los atributos son obtenidos desde el SDK

En el caso de usar :

```
?attr
```

Los atributos son obtenidos por definición realizada en tu aplicación, por ejemplo en el archivo  `attrs.xml`.

---

Esto es similar a obtener otras propiedades como el color, por ejemplo, en este caso obtenemos un color definido en nuestro archivo `colors.xml`:

```
android:background="@color/black"
```

Pero podemos obtener el color definido en el SDK por medio de `@android:`

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia es que `?attr` son referencias a valores que tu haz creado mientras que `?android:attr` son valores listos, incorporados y disponibles en Android.